# Java: while loop not working

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, input, while-loop

I want to check the users input when a new game is created, and see if it is y, n, or neither.

For some reason it skips the while loop all together and just outputs "Welcome to Questions."

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questions {

public static final Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(System.in);

private boolean ans;


public Questions() {

  while (ans = false) {
      System.out.print("Do you want to start a new game (y/n)?: ");
      String input = INPUT.nextLine();

      if (input == "y"){
          ans = true;
          //some code
      }

      else if (input == "n"){
          ans = true;
          //some code
      }

      else {
          System.out.println("Invalid input, Try again");
          ans = false;
      }

  }//end while

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Questions game = new Questions();
  System.out.println("Welcome to Questions.");

}
```

Comment: You have initialized your ans to false

Comment: You don't compare strings with `==`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @redFIVE not a duplicate because that is a problem but there is another problem that needs to be fixed first...see my answer.

Comment: @brso05 well its for sure going to be the next java 101 with zero research question thats going to get asked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (ans = false) {
```

Should be:

```
while (ans == false) {
```

`=` is for assignment `==` is for checking equality

Also `Strings` are compared using `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` not `==`:

```
if (input == "y"){
```

Should be:

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
```

Comment: @redFIVE your right I didn't notice that the first time...I added that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change private boolean ans to

```
private boolean ans = false;
```

or use **do while loop**

Also comparison is done using **==** not **=**

Comment: except for strings, which OP is doing